# struct without constructors containing std::variant containing array cannot be returned by value?

Tags: c++, std-variant

In C++ I want to return a struct by value which contains a variant with an array inside. The struct has no explicit constructors. Is this not possible?

In the following I get the compiler error (gcc):

*"error: use of deleted function 'TestStruct2::TestStruct2(const TestStruct2&)'"*

It works, if I define constructors. I don't want constructors here.

```
struct TestStruct2
{
    std::variant<int[5], float[4]> t;
};

TestStruct2 test2()
{
    TestStruct2 t;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Replace your arrays with `std::array`. Problem solved.

Comment: raw arrays are not copyable.

Comment: I didn't expect `std::variant` to work with raw arrays at all.

Comment: Nathan: Is this also true for copiing the struct? There is no compilation error if I place raw arrays inside the struct without the variant.

Comment: @ErnieMur As a member of a struct or class the array will be copied for you by the default copy constructor.  Outside of that, you cannot copy an array.  `variant` checks if the types it contains are copyable and since an array by itself is not, it makes the variant non-copyable.

Comment: @NathanOliver   So it would also work to wrap the array into an additional struct?

Comment: @ErnieMur Yes, but there is no need to do that yourself.  Just use `std::array` which does this for you.

Comment: "So it would also work to wrap the array into an additional struct?" Yes. That's exactly what `std::array` does.

Comment: My compiler says `error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'integral_constant<bool, false>::value' "variant can not have an array type as an alternative."` ... which jibes with HolyBlackCat's comment.